# Wigner 3j-symbol in mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I am looking for a nice and workable formulation of the 3j-symbol in terms of hypergeometric functions.

On the Wolfram webpage, I found [this](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/ThreeJSymbol/26/01/02/0001/).

Unfortunately, no explanation of the function `PhysicalQ` is given. What does it mean? I would also be interested to know how to call this reformulation of the Wigner symbol in terms of the right-hand-side expression in Mathematica. Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: `PhysicalQ` is likely enforcing physically allowed choices (selection rules) of the `l`s and `m`s.  For instance, $m_1+m_2=m_3$ and $|m_1|\leq l_1$; in the documentation, it says that `ThreeJSymbol` will return 0 and an error message, but for some reason I don't get the error message when the choices of l and m are unphysical.

Comment: In addition, `l`s should fulfill triangle inequality.

Comment: @march, ideally, *Mathematica* is supposed to emit a warning message if any arguments do not correspond to physically relevant values, but it will still evaluate the underlying hypergeometric function through analytic continuation. Consider making a report to Support for the cases where you expect a warning message, but do not see one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Unfortunately, no explanantion of the function `PhysicalQ` is given. What does it mean?

If you had browsed the Wolfram Functions site more thoroughly, you would have found the ["Primary Definition" page](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/ThreeJSymbol/02/) for `ThreeJSymbol[]`, and then you would have seen the required definitions for `PhysicalQ[]` and the associated function `TriangularQ[]` (which yarchik has astutely guessed in the comments as a required condition).

For convenience, here is a *Mathematica* rendering of the definition for `PhysicalQ`:

```
PhysicalQ[{j1, m1}, {j2, m2}, {j3, m3}] == TriangularQ[j1, j2, j3] && 
          j1 - m1 ∈ Integers && j2 - m2 ∈ Integers && j3 - m3 ∈ Integers &&
          -j1 <= m1 <= j1 && -j2 <= m2 <= j2 && -j3 <= m3 <= j3
```

where

```
TriangularQ[j1, j2, j3] == (2 j1 ∈ Integers && j1 >= 0) && (2 j2 ∈ Integers && j2 >= 0) &&
                           (2 j3 ∈ Integers && j3 >= 0) &&
                           (j1 + j2 + j3 ∈ Integers && j1 + j2 + j3 >= 0) &&
                           Abs[j1 - j2] <= j3 <= j1 + j2
```